# No need for an account to display Mapbox maps on a website?

Tags: google-maps

I am looking for replacing google maps on my website with 'mapbox'

I looked at the example given by mapbox : http://mapbox.com/hosting/mapbox-streets/
There is no reference to a mapbox account in the source code, (no API ID like in google maps).

Does that mean there is no need for an account ??? does that means it is free ?

Comment: It's old, but for future generations : https://www.mapbox.com/plans/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get an account at mapbox and contribute by honestly assessing your usage limits and subscribing to the plan that is right for you.  For now there isn't any code or api key that you need to enter when you are using their services.  I imagine they will be implementing metering sometime soon.  In the future you should update SO posts if you get an official answer at a support forum, it helps us all! ;)

Official answer to your same question posted at mapbox support site:
http://support.mapbox.com/discussions/general-questions/1119-no-need-for-an-account-to-display-mapbox-maps-on-a-website

See 
http://mapbox.com/mobile/platforms/
For open source implementations you can use that work with the appropriat eformats.

More info on the mapbox API - 
http://mapbox.com/hosting/api/